# Aggregation for all tables in DB

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

All tables in my database contain the same column, call it `date_marked_invalid`. I would like to find the `MAX()` over this columns for all tables. Is there a way to obtain these without having to run

```sql
SELECT MAX(date_marked_invalid) FROM one_particular_table
```

separately for each individual table?

For Postgres [hackery like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330331/1291563) would do the trick but this doesn't work on Snowflake as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIN/MAX values of all columns are stored in the metadata for each table, but unfortunately not accessible in eg. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

If you create a stored procedure that iterates over the tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` it still is a "metadata only" operation, but has to be done manually.

Snowflake doesn't have any functions that can run dynamic SQL like Postgres' `query_to_xml()`

A query to dynamically generate an aggregation statement would be in the line of

```
SELECT
  'SELECT MAX(MX) FROM ('
   || LISTAGG(CHR(10)||'  SELECT MAX('||COLUMN_NAME||') MX FROM '
   || TABLE_CATALOG||'.'||TABLE_SCHEMA||'.'||TABLE_NAME, ' UNION')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL)||CHR(10)||')' COL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME;
```

Comment: How would I create such a stored procedure?

Comment: If you have a fixed set of tables, use a `UNION ALL` construct with the `MAX()` values for each table.  I you want a dynamic statement, you can generate it using something like the query above in a stored procedure (see https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html for hints).  Unfortunately, there is no fully flexible way to get the result value from a stored procedure into eg. a query.

Answer (score 0):

I used an untidy approach in the past when as a developer, I did not have access to any system tables in the traditional RDBMS world. I used show tables to get the list of all tables and then use excel to generate max(date_marked_invalid)) with an additional alias column as table name and then applied union all to build a result.

```
select max(date_marked_invalid) as dt, 'table-1' as table from table-1 union all
select max(date_marked_invalid) as dt, 'table-2' as table from table-2 union all
select max(date_marked_invalid) as dt, 'table-3' as table from table-3
```

The result may appear like

```
enter code here
dt        |  table
01-01-2020 table-1
01-02-2020 table-2
```

Once you have the list of tables, you can format all your queries like this and get the result. If this is a job task and should run a job, then some scripting language or programming language can help here where show table output is captured in a file, build a query like this and get the result.

I hope this untidy approach may be temporarily helpful.